# Выложить сайт на GitHub, или нет, имея чужой измененный код?

Tags: javascript, html, css, git, codepen

Встал вопрос с сайтом, выложить на GitHub? Есть боязнь по незнанию лицензионных соглашений использования чужого кода с сайта Codepen, и взаимодействия GitHub.  Понимаю, что вопрос может быть избитым и наверняка есть ответ, но я не нашел полного ответа на этот вопрос.

Если я укажу все ссылки на Codepen владельцев кода в Html главной, без публикации, а именно в самом коде страницы. Будет ли мне ататат за использование чужого кода? Или же лучше не выкладывать такой сайт на GitHub?
Сайт не предназначен для заработка. Это каталог клипов ссылками на YouTube.

Comment: Не парьтесь насчёт codepen ...он общественный т.е можно пользоваться сколько угодно в любых целях ...но ради порядочности указывайте ссылку на первоисточник

Comment: https://blog.codepen.io/legal/licensing/

Comment: @MaximLensky надо уточнить, что только публичные «пены», а приватные могут быть под какой угодно лицензией, зависит от автора.

Comment: Ребята, спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodePen является открытым источником. Вы можете спокойно использовать код в некоммерческих целях, но всё же оставьте ссылки на первоисточник/авторов.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, код на CodePen лицензируется по MIT лицензии, что разрешает использовать его в коммерческих проектах. Или я не прав?

Comment: Насколько я понял, вы можете использовать код с CodePen в любых целях, но при этом ваш код должен иметь такую же лицензию. Исключением может быть указание лицензии в самом коде, тогда уже нужно быть осторожнее с использованием чужой работы. Поправьте, если что то не так.